# Installing praw on a mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, reddit, praw

I have already installed homebrew and pip. When I run $pip install praw the following comes up:

```
dhcp-215-185:~ my_name$ pip install praw
Downloading/unpacking praw
  Downloading praw-2.1.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70kB): 70kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking update-checker>=0.10 (from praw)
  Downloading update_checker-0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking requests>=1.2.0 (from praw)
  Downloading requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (625kB): 625kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.4 (from praw)
  Downloading six-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: praw, update-checker, requests, six
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
os.makedirs(destdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/my_name/Library/Logs/pip.log
dhcp-215-185:~ my_name$
```

Does anyone have a fix? Installing this has been a real headache. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you're running the system `pip` (in `/usr/bin/pip`). If you installed via Homebrew, set up your `$PATH` to run `/usr/local/bin/pip` instead.

Comment: @mipadi Thanks! Sorry, but I'm new at this. How exactly would I set that up? Again, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to use the `sudo pip install praw` command to intall praw as a super-user. However, this is not recommended, as it can cause problems later on with things such as updates and scaling your application upwards. One would instead suggest that you [create a virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), and `pip install praw` inside it.

If you are confident that the application you are building will not grow too large, it is probably ok to install praw using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you and I found an answer in the [reddit documentation for PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html). I used HomeBrew to install pip and I'm using Python 3.x instead of the 2.7x that's shipped with OSX, which means I needed to use pip3 instead of pip. It worked right away.

I hope this helps!